# Display or get the HTTP header attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I have an application developed in Rails and I am trying to see the attributes in the HTTP header.

Is there any way to read these attributes? Where are they stored?

Someone mentioned `request.headers`. Is this correct? I am not able to see any attributes inside this array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code solved my question `request.env["HTTP_MY_HEADER"]`. The trick was that I had to prefix my header's name with `HTTP`

Comment: it looks like `request.headers['HTTP_MY_HEADER']` would also work.

Answer (score 48):

`request.headers` does not return a hash, but an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::Headers`, which is a wrapper around rack env.

`ActionDispatch::Http::Headers` implements many methods like `[]` and `[]=` which make it behave like a hash, but it doesn't override the default `inspect`, hence you can't see the key-value pairs by just `p` or `pp` it.

You can, however, see the request headers in the rack env:

```
pp request.headers.env.select{|k, _| k =~ /^HTTP_/}
```

Remember that the request headers in rack env are the `upcase`d, `underscore`d and `HTTP_` prefixed version of the original http request headers.

## UPDATE

Actually there are a finite set of request headers that are not prefixed `HTTP_`. These (capitalized and underscored) header names are stored in `ActionDispatch::Http::Headers::CGI_VARIABLES`. I list them below:

```
    AUTH_TYPE
    CONTENT_LENGTH
    CONTENT_TYPE
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE
    HTTPS
    PATH_INFO
    PATH_TRANSLATED
    QUERY_STRING
    REMOTE_ADDR
    REMOTE_HOST
    REMOTE_IDENT
    REMOTE_USER
    REQUEST_METHOD
    SCRIPT_NAME
    SERVER_NAME
    SERVER_PORT
    SERVER_PROTOCOL
    SERVER_SOFTWARE
```

So the full version of listing request headers would be

```
pp request.headers.env.select{|k, _| k.in?(ActionDispatch::Http::Headers::CGI_VARIABLES) || k =~ /^HTTP_/}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, cause I keep getting all the attributes prefixed with `HTTP`, why I can't I access it with something like `response['Cache-Control']`

Comment: @user3433309 You absolutely can access the request headers like `request.headers['Authorization']`. Rails wraps the rack env for just this reason. You can take a look at the source code of `ActionDispatch::Http::Headers`, it's very simple.

Comment: I was able to access an attribute, an OAuth2 signature in my case, using either, `request.headers.env['HTTP_X_PROVIDER_SIGNATURE']` or `request.headers['X-Provider-Signature']`. A Rails5 application.

Answer (score 7):

I've noticed in Rails 5 they now expect headers to be spelled like this in the request:

`Access-Token`

Before they are transformed into:

`HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

In Rails. Doing `ACCESS_TOKEN` will no longer work.

Answer (score -3):

You can see hash of actual http headers using `@_headers` in controller.